# Cannot Find Post requests when filling out the form

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to practice my skills with requests, so I'm trying to basically make a script that keeps entering emails on this page [hgtv](https://www.hgtv.com/design/hgtv-dream-home), but when I type the email in and click enter, I can't find the post requests that it sends, how do I find it? I looked all over the Chrome developer tools network tab, and could not find the post requests with my email in it.

Comment: What does this have to do with python?  From your description, you're just using the browser normally.

Comment: Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far and you'll get.